# HtDP / Chpt. 5: How do I use "symbol=?"? (Scheme)

Tags: scheme

I'm currently working through HtDP on my own.

In Chapter 5 "Symbolic Information" is covered. The example in the text is:

```
(define (reply s)
  (cond
    [(symbol=? s 'GoodMorning) 'Hi]
    [(symbol=? s 'HowAreYou?) 'Fine]
    [(symbol=? s 'GoodAfternoon) 'INeedANap]
    [(symbol=? s 'GoodEvening) 'BoyAmITired]))
```

That's all clear. However, the second exercise asks:

Exercise 5.1.2. Develop the function check-guess. It consumes two numbers, guess and target. Depending on how guess relates to target, the function produces one of the following three answers: 'TooSmall, 'Perfect, or 'TooLarge.

Frankly, I don't really see when or why "symbol=?" comes in here. My solution only uses "cond". [EDIT: Code removed due to a suggestion since it is a solution to a textbook exercise.]

According to the text, "symbol=?" consumes two symbols and returns either true or false, depending on whether they are identical or not.

I fear that I am now deep into the realm of the Dunning-Kruger effect, but I really don't see a way to implement this piece of code with the use of "symbol=?". "cond" is covered in Chapter 4, which is why I am now confused.

Any help is highly appreciated.

If you want to have a look at the chapter in HtDP, then please go here:
http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-8.html#node_sec_5.1

Unfortunately, the solutions are only accessible with a password.

Comment: The solution is to stop second guessing yourself! The code definition part of your answer is fine. You are, however, missing the contract and purpose :). Just because it was covered in chapter 3 doesn't mean you stop using it in Chapter 5. Similarly, though comparisons were in chapter 4, having a program use comparisons to return symbols is new. Now, I'm personally of the opinion that you should delete this question since you post too much of the answer for students who actually get assigned this as homework.

Comment: ccoakley,
thank for very much your fast response! So the "symbol" is the text that is given as a response? However, where does "symbol=?" come into play? Since the whole set of exercises in chapter 5 is called "finger exercises with symbols" I just don't quite see how this exercises fits into the chapter otherwise.

I'll edit part of the question.

Comment: That leading tic in `'TooSmall` makes that a symbol (without it, scheme would look for a variable with that name). `symbol=?` doesn't come into play in that exercise, though you are meant to imagine a game that used your program and then used `symbol=?` to generate the next guess... you play that part in the next exercise. Also, it was good that you posted your code in the first place (so we could confirm that your definition was correct), but thanks for taking it down.

Comment: Thanks again! I just finished chapter 5, and a lot has cleared up now, also due to your helpful elaborations.

Answer (score -1):

use < and > to compare the numbers. You can't to use symbol=? for this.